# Pandas finding dates lower than current row' date group by type

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with id, number and date. I want to create a new column as below. Basically, groupby type and find the dates which are between two years of current id's date.

```
id  type    date    
1   a   2023-06-18  
2   a   2022-06-18  
3   a   2021-06-18  
4   b   2023-06-18  
5   b   2020-06-18  
6   c   2023-06-18  

        
id  type    date    past_records_in_2_years
1   a   2023-06-18  2
2   a   2022-06-18  1
3   a   2021-06-18  0
4   b   2023-06-18  0
5   b   2020-06-18  0
6   c   2023-06-18  0
```

I tried using for loop but I have 1M+ rows so it is taking too much time.

```
for i in range(len(df)):

  temp = df[df['type'] == df.loc[i]['type']].reset_index(drop = True)

  if len(temp) > 1:

    past_dates = 0

    for j in range(len(temp)):

      if (temp.loc[j]['date'] - df.loc[i]['date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y') < 3:

        past_dates += 1

    if past_dates >= 2:

      df[i]['date'] = 1

    else:

      df[i]['date'] = 0

  else:

    df[i]['date'] = 0
```

Comment: Merge and filter?

Answer (score 1):

pandas merge and filter should suffice:

```py
other = pd.DataFrame({'type': df['type'],
                      'present':df.date, 
                      'two_yrs_ahead' : df.date.add(pd.DateOffset(years=2))})
(df.merge(
     other,
     on = 'type'
    )
.assign(counts = lambda f: f.date.gt(f.present) & 
                           f.date.le(f.two_yrs_ahead))
.groupby(df.columns.tolist())
.counts
.sum()
)

id  type  date
1   a     2023-06-18    2
2   a     2022-06-18    1
3   a     2021-06-18    0
4   b     2023-06-18    0
5   b     2020-06-18    0
6   c     2023-06-18    0
Name: counts, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Above code returns an empty series object.

Comment: I think we need to perform  2 things.
1. We have to group by data with type, that is fairly easy.
2. For each group we have to individually look into each row and check if there are other ids with less than 2 years of dates.

for the second approach I could not think of anything besides running for loop

Comment: Empty series? Based on the data you shared?

Comment: Yes! bases on the data I shared

Comment: Really? Can't be an empty series. The data you shared is what I used. Break it down. Did the merge return an empty dataframe? Was it the assign function? Again, if it is based on the data you shared, then no not an empty series

Comment: You do a pair of comparisons between `f` and `present`: both `.gt()` and `.ne()`. But GT implies NE. Is there maybe some `NaN` consideration going on that you wanted to document in a comment?

Comment: My bad, the ne is not needed

Comment: Thanks for your input. @sammywemmy Your code does work on above code but when I try to use it on my actual data which is pretty similar, it return an empty list

Comment: Empty series* I have tried a different approach. I have created another column with date2(current id's date - 2 year).