# Pandas group by number and find dates lowers than current date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-preprocessing

I have the pandas dataframe with id, number and date. I want to create a new column which shows how many dates are lower than current id's date with same number(group by number).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'number':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'date' : ['2023-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2021-06-20', '2021-07-20', '2022-06-20', '2023-06-20']})
print(df)

  id number        date
0   1      a  2023-06-20
1   2      a  2022-06-20
2   3      a  2021-06-20
3   4      a  2021-07-20
4   5      b  2022-06-20
5   6      c  2023-06-20
```

I have used pandas apply function with filtering. The issue is I have 300k+ rows and it is taking around 2 hours to run below code. How do I optimize this?

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x:len(df[(df['number'] == x['number']) & (df['date'] < x['date'])]), axis = 1)
print(df)
 id number        date    result
0   1      a  2023-06-20     3
1   2      a  2022-06-20     2
2   3      a  2021-06-20     0
3   4      a  2021-07-20     1
4   5      b  2022-06-20     0
5   6      c  2023-06-20     0
```

Comment: Are the data unique within a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort your dataframe by `date` then compute the cumulative count for each group:

```
df['result'] = df.sort_values('date').groupby('number').cumcount()
print(df)

# Output
   id number        date  result
0   1      a  2023-06-20       3
1   2      a  2022-06-20       2
2   3      a  2021-06-20       0
3   4      a  2021-07-20       1
4   5      b  2022-06-20       0
5   6      c  2023-06-20       0
```

Note: it works only because `date` are unique in your dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize your code to calculate the desired result more efficiently. Instead of using the `apply` function, you can leverage the power of pandas `groupby` and `cumcount` functions. These functions allow you to perform the desired calculations without the need for nested loops.

Here's the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'number': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'date': ['2023-06-20', '2022-06-20', '2021-06-20', '2021-07-20', '2022-06-20', '2023-06-20']})

# Calculate the result using groupby and cumcount
df['result'] = df.groupby('number')['date'].cumcount()

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Reference:

Pandas documentation on [grouby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
Pandas documentation on [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the other answers, if your dates are unique a simple `groupby.cumcount` on the sorted values will work.

If you can have duplicates the result will be incorrect and the  computation becomes more complex.

You then need to compute the number of occurrences per dates/id, then a `cumsum` of those values:

```
tmp = (df.sort_values(by=['number', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])
   .groupby(['date', 'number'], as_index=False).size()
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('number')['size'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)))
 )

df['result'] = df.merge(tmp, on=['date', 'number'], how='left')['n']
                   
 
   id number        date  result
0   1      a  2023-06-20       3
1   2      a  2022-06-20       2
2   3      a  2021-06-20       0
3   4      a  2021-07-20       1
4   5      b  2022-06-20       0
5   6      c  2023-06-20       0
```

Example of difference when dates are duplicated:

```
   id number        date  result  cumcount
0   0      a  2022-06-20       2         2
1   1      a  2023-06-20       4         4
2   2      a  2022-06-20       2         3
3   3      a  2021-06-20       0         0
4   4      a  2021-07-20       1         1
5   5      b  2022-06-20       0         0
6   6      c  2023-06-20       0         0
```

Comment: Yes! I did not consider the duplicates. This is perfect. Thank you

Comment: can you also help me with this? Thank you in advance. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503279/pandas-finding-dates-lower-than-current-row-date-group-by-type

Comment: Note that I just changed something in the answer (used `shift` to avoid counting rows that are equal to itself)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `rank()`

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('number')['date'].rank(method = 'min').sub(1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   id number       date  result
0   1      a 2023-06-20       3
1   2      a 2022-06-20       2
2   3      a 2021-06-20       0
3   4      a 2021-07-20       1
4   5      b 2022-06-20       0
5   6      c 2023-06-20       0
```